# Trying to update a textbox with a start-job and a register-objectevent

Tags: powershell, start-job

i made this script that create a timer and get the infomration inside a job

```
function get-pingtest { 
    $script:timer1 = New-Object System.Timers.Timer 
    $timer1.Interval = 200 
    $timer1.AutoReset = $true 
    $timer1.Start()
    $PingArgs = @{
        TargetName = "google.com"
        count = 2
        BufferSize = 64
        TimeoutSeconds = 1
    }
    $TimerArgs = @{
        InputObject = $Timer1
        EventName = 'Elapsed'
        SourceIdentifier = 'Timer.Ping'
        Action = { 
            if ((get-job -Name Ping).state -eq "Stopped"){
                $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping
                Write-host ($JobOutput)
                if ($null -eq $JobOutput) {
                    $timer1.Stop()
                    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier *
                    remove-job -name * -force
                }
            }
            if ((get-job -name Ping).state -eq "Failed"){
                $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping 2>&1
                Write-Host "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"
                $timer1.Stop()
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier *
                remove-job -name * -force
            }
            if ((get-job -name Ping).state -eq "Completed"){
                $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping 2>&1
                if ($null -eq $JobOutput) {
                    $timer1.Stop()
                    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier *
                    remove-job -name * -force
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"
                }
            }
            if ((get-job -name Ping).state -eq "Running"){
                $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping
                if ($null -eq $JobOutput) {}
                else {Write-Host "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"}
            }
        }
    }
    Start-Job -name Ping -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection @using:PingArgs}
    Register-ObjectEvent @TimerArgs
}
```

and works as intended it retrive the information without any problem even if there is some error in the job process

but when i insert it in my program sometings goes wrong the script in my program is this

```
function start-advancedpingtimed  {
    $script:timer1 = New-Object System.Timers.Timer 
    $timer1.Interval = 200 
    $timer1.AutoReset = $true 
    $timer1.Start()
$PingArgs = @{
    TargetName = "google.com"
    count = 2
    BufferSize = 64
    TimeoutSeconds = 1
}
$TimerArgs = @{
    InputObject = $Timer1
    EventName = 'Elapsed'
    SourceIdentifier = 'Timer.Ping'
    Action = {  
        if ((get-job -Name Ping).state -eq "Stopped"){
            $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping
            if ($null -eq $JobOutput) {
                $timer1.Stop()
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier *
                remove-job -name * -force
            }
            else {Write-toOutputBox "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"}
        }
        if ((get-job -name Ping).state -eq "Failed"){
            $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping 2>&1
            Write-toOutputBox -iserror "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"
            $timer1.Stop()
            Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier *
            remove-job -name * -force
        }
        if ((get-job -name Ping).state -eq "Completed"){
            $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping 2>&1
            if ($null -eq $JobOutput) {
                $timer1.Stop()
                Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier *
                remove-job -name * -force
            }
            else {Write-toOutputBox "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"}
        }
        if ((get-job -name Ping).state -eq "Running"){
            $JobOutput = receive-job -Name Ping
            if ($null -eq $JobOutput) {}
            else {Write-toOutputBox "$($JobOutput | Out-String)"}
        }
    }
}
Start-Job -name Ping -ScriptBlock {Test-Connection @using:PingArgs}
Register-ObjectEvent @TimerArgs
}
```

and this is the script to update the text box

```
function Write-toOutputBox {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [array]$Message,
        [switch]$clear,
        [switch]$iserror
    )
    if($clear){$wpf.TextBox_Output.Clear()}
    if ($iserror) {$wpf.TextBox_Output.Foreground = "Red"}
    else {$wpf.TextBox_Output.Foreground = "Black"}
    foreach($m in $Message) {
        if ($null -ne $m) {
            $wpf.TextBox_Output.text += "$m `r"
            $wpf.TextBox_Output.ScrollToEnd()
        }
        else{continue}
    }
}
```

so when start the function from the gui, either powershel inside vs code crashes,
or dont update anyting end by closing the gui, watching inside the textbox variable i see the results

Comment: The problem is because System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread than the form.  You can, instead, use Forms.Timer since it runs on the same thread.  But this works only as long as the timer click event is short and  sweet.  But if you are trying to do something that takes a long time, then the form will freeze until the click event is finished.  There might be a way to have both timers access the same variable so the system timer does the long event, saving the results, and the form timer updates.  Searching for BeginInvoke will get you mostly C# examples, but a PS version may be doable.

Comment: ty ill search for it

Comment: ok solved with your advice now i use a combination of jobs and runspace timers ty for your help

Comment: You are welcome, and glad you have a solution!  Sorry I didn't have a complete answer. I'm familiar with the problem in the context of C#, but never tried to solve it in PS.